# Nested Case is giving wrong outout

Tags: sql-server, count, case

I am trying to copy into another table the number of rows under specific conditions (how many times customers had orders in the timespan of 2021-2022 & in specific publication & the order status is done).
I have used nested case when option for this. However, I am getting wrong numbers (all rows, not just the rows with the case criteria met).

What is wrong with the code?

```sql
Insert into table 1 (Cust_ID, freq)
Select Cust_ID, COUNT(
CASE WHEN  PublicationIntName NOT LIKE '%yyy%' then
        case when Created Between '01.01.2021' and '31.12.2022' then
            case when AdStatusName like 'xxx' then 1 else 0 END
        else 0 end
else 0 end)
FROM table 2
Group by table 2. Cust_ID;
```

[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8GgY.png)
[Power BI Check to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8GgY.png)

Here are the screenshots from the Query Output (incorrect) and my doble-check filtering (the same data from SQL Server) in Power BI.
As you see, the query (any versions I tried) returns number of all rows (not just those, when the case criteria is met).

Comment: *"[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8GgY.png) [Power BI Check to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8GgY.png)"* [They're the same picture](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/027/752/6lwrp2xhplg41.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` *counts* the number of non-`NULL` values. All routes in your `CASE` lead to `1` or `0`, which are both not `NULL`. You only need to return `1` for the rows you want to `COUNT`; the `ELSE 0` should be removed.

I truth, however, there's no need for the nested `CASE` expressions, just use a single one:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 (Cust_ID, freq)
SELECT Cust_ID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PublicationIntName NOT LIKE '%yyy%' 
                   AND Created >= '20210101' AND Created < '20230101' --Use date rangse, as BETWEEN can miss things if Created is a date and tiem value
                   AND AdStatusName = 'xxx' THEN 1 --Used equals as xxx isn't a pattern
             END)
FROM dbo.table2
GROUP BY table2.Cust_ID;
```

Comment: Yes, it schema qualifies, uses `=` and uses date ranges, @TimBiegeleisen , and my "answer" was initially in the comments in less specific terms until I migrated it. Plus it explains why `COUNT` isn't working as the user expects, yours does not. So yes, quite different.

Comment: For the column "Created" I have a datetime data type. And using only one Case expression was my first choice. However I did not work as well. Even when I write full datetime format '01.01.2021 00:00:00" It does not give me the right output. The output (the number of rows) in all of mycodes I tried gives me all rows number, the query does not filter it through any of the case's conditions

Comment: If the above is still counting every row, @Val , then *every* row have a value of `'xxx'` for `AdStatusName`, `PublicationIntName` *doesn't* contain `'yyy'` and all the rows are in 2021 or 2022. So it's counting every row, because every row is applicable. You'll need to provide a [mre] here.

Comment: I do a check in Power BI (I am connected to SQL Server) and I filter Customer IDs to see if SQL Query gives me  correct output.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, @Val , It works as expected: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jCDU2NxB)

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM()`, since `COUNT()` will count any non null row :

```
Insert into table 1 (Cust_ID, freq)
Select Cust_ID, SUM(
CASE WHEN  PublicationIntName NOT LIKE '%yyy%' then
        case when Created Between '01.01.2021' and '31.12.2022' then
            case when AdStatusName like 'xxx' then 1 else 0 END
        else 0 end
else 0 end)
FROM table 2
Group by table 2. Cust_ID;
```

Comment: I get 0 as teh output if I use SUM instead of Count